# Edit distance algorithm special issue

Tags: python

my first post here.

I'm writing generic edit distance algorithm for online course. I've tried to test it and don't see problem with it yet the online testing system shows I'm failing one of the tests without saying where the problem is.
The long "if" clause is for special case when algorithm fails to add "1" like for example strings "aab" and "aba" where I was getting distance of 1 instead of 2.

So what I'm trying to do here is find border cases for which my algorithm doesn't work.

I'm actually surprised because I wrote this following directions from a book and I'm pretty sure algorithm in the book would fail on these special cases as well.

this is the code:

```
def editDistance(string1, string2):

    string1 = list(string1)
    string2 = list(string2)

    m = len(string1)
    n = len(string2)

    matrix = []

    matrix.append([])

    for i in range(0, m+1):
        matrix[0].append(i)

    for j in range(1, n+1):
        matrix.append([j])

    for j in range(1, n+1):
        for i in range(1, m+1):
            minimum = min(matrix[j][i-1],matrix[j-1][i],matrix[j-1][i-1])

            if i > 1 and string1[i-1] == string1[i-2] == string2[i-2] != string2[i-1] and minimum == 0:
                matrix[j].append(1)
            elif string1[i-1] == string2[j-1]:
                matrix[j].append(minimum)
            else:
                matrix[j].append(minimum + 1)

    #for _ in range(n+1):
        #print(matrix[_])

    return matrix[n][m]


entry1 = input()
entry2 = input()

print(editDistance(entry1,entry2))
```

Answer (score 0):

`Edit Distance` carries some ambiguity, as there are several ways to measure it [See Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance)

You'd get a distance of 1 if you are calculating the Damerau-Levenshtein distance because there are 4 string operation each with cost 1 (insertion, deletion, substitution, adjacent transposition).

Plain old Levenshtein would give you 2 because there are 3 operations (insertion, deletion & substitution).

Your implementation looks very similar to the pseudo-code [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance).

I'm guessing the site you are submitting your attempts to is expecting the Levenshtein

Comment: Oh gosh, I thought he meant to edit his algortihm. As an addition to this, check out hamming distance, if both strings have the same number of characters. It is very similar to Levenshtein.

Comment: It should be plain Levenshtein because it allows insertion, deletion and substitution each with cost of 1. I'll check the links though, may clarify things.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I have checked original Levenshtein and Damerau-Levenshtein as well. Problem is in order of checking for minimum and adding 1.

What I did is I was checking for minimum in three surrounding cells and then when I found it I would add 1.

What I should have done is calculate each cell with adding 1(or not adding 1 in case when cell is (i-1)(j-1) and letters are equal) and then choose minimum from those.

This is correct code:

def editDistance(string1, string2):

```
string1 = list(string1)
string2 = list(string2)

m = len(string1)
n = len(string2)

matrix = []

matrix.append([])

for i in range(0, m+1):
    matrix[0].append(i)

for j in range(1, n+1):
    matrix.append([j])

for j in range(1, n+1):
    for i in range(1, m+1):

        insertion = matrix[j][i-1] + 1
        deletion = matrix[j-1][i] + 1

        if string1[i-1] == string2[j-1]:
            substitution = matrix[j-1][i-1]
        else:
            substitution = matrix[j-1][i-1] + 1

        minimum = min(insertion,deletion,substitution)

        matrix[j].append(minimum)

#for _ in range(n+1):
    #print(matrix[_])

return matrix[n][m]
```

entry1 = input()
entry2 = input()

print(editDistance(entry1,entry2))